# Total range of cells in multiple workbooks from a file

Tags: excel, vba, sum

What I am trying to do is create a master file that has the totals of all of the files in a workbook. However, I do not have the files that need to be totaled, yet.

It is for an expense report, my team will fill out their expense reports and save them in a folder on the network. Then I want to be able to run a macro that totals the range (L15:L31) of all the files in the folder (G:\Common\212\Expense Reports). There will will be a large, and constantly growing number of files in the formula, so anything where I have to select the individual files would be impractical.

As an example:

ExpenseReport1.xls has the values

```
L15 4
L16 5
L17 6
```

ExpenseReport2.xls has the values

```
L15 8
L16 1
L17 3
```

I want my Totals file to total those together and come back with

```
L15 12
L16 6
L17 9
```

Comment: You can use Dir() to loop over all of the files in a folder, open each one and extract the ranges you need.

Answer (score 0):

To get the folder path, the below macro gives the option to choose one of the source files. It then looks into each of the Expense Reports in that folder and adds those values to the master spreadsheet.

Assumtions:

 - all source file are .xls files and their names start with "ExpenseReport"

 - there's only one sheet in each workbook (in case it's not so, just need to add sheet ref as well)

```
Sub imptrn()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim myFile As String, pth As String, listResult As Variant, mastBook As Workbook, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Set mastBook = ThisWorkbook
    ChDrive mastBook.path
    ChDir mastBook.path
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Expense Reports (*.xls),*.xls")
    If myFile = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open myFile
    pth = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\ExpenseReport*.xls"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    listResult = fileList(pth)
    Select Case IsArray(listResult)
        Case True
            mastBook.Sheets(1).Range("L5:L17").ClearContents
            For i = LBound(listResult) To UBound(listResult)
                Workbooks.Open fileName:=listResult(i)
                For j = 15 To 17
                    mastBook.Sheets(1).Range("L" & j) = mastBook.Sheets(1).Range("L" & j) + Range("L" & j)
                Next j
                ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
                If i = UBound(listResult) Then MsgBox "Totals updated."
            Next i
        Case False
            MsgBox "No matching files"
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
Function fileList(filePath As String) As Variant 'returns an array of fileNames, or False if no matching file found
    Dim fileArray() As Variant, fileCount As Integer, fileName As String
    On Error GoTo NoFilesFound
    fileCount = 0
    fileName = Dir(filePath)
    If fileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound
    Do While fileName <> ""
        fileCount = fileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve fileArray(1 To fileCount)
        fileArray(fileCount) = fileName
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
    fileList = fileArray
    Exit Function
NoFilesFound:
    fileList = False
End Function
```

Comment: There are multiple sheets in each workbook, the one I would be sourcing is the second sheet, and titled "expense report." The first assumption is correct.

Comment: ya in that case just change this code (line# 20 i guess) `mastBook.Sheets(1).Range("L" & j) = mastBook.Sheets(1).Range("L" & j) + Range("L" & j)` to `mastBook.Sheets(1).Range("L" & j) = mastBook.Sheets(1).Range("L" & j) + Sheets(2).Range("L" & j)`